# Suggestion For Create Ticketing Apps VB.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I wanna ask about my ticketing/coupon apps. First, I am trying to create this apps with PHP and export it into PDF file. But failed.
And now, I want to create this using `VB.NET` and `Crystal Report` to create printable version of the coupon.

As I know, in the crystal report the value will repeat by row. Like

```
1

2

3
```

That's not what I want, **I want the value repeated in 3 column**.

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

How to do this in crystal report?
(Suggestion for another reporting tools are welcome)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which version of Crystal reports columns were introduced but in section expert of crystal report select detail section. Select detail section. If your version has a selection for Format with multiple columns select that box.  From there select the layout tab and enter the desired width and select Across then down.

Never found this to be overly useful except to print labels.